# Simple calculation with if function not working

Tags: objective-c

Ok guys, i've got a simple calculation that's not working.

I'll give a really basic example of the problem.

I have a KG Button and a Pounds button. If the KG button is selected, float weight is the value in my weight text box. If the Pounds button is select, I divide the number in the weight text box by 2.2 and make it float weight.

I've written an if function for this and at the end, I want to multiply weight and age. Age is just whatever number is in the age text box.

```
-(IBAction)calculate;
{
    //put age value into a float
    float age = ([valAge.text floatValue]);


    //Put weight value into a float
    if (btnKG.selected = YES)
    {
        float weight = ([valWeight.text floatValue]);
    }
    else
    {
        float weight = ([valWeight.text floatValue]/2.20462);
    }



    //calculate
    float bmr = weight * age;



}
```

I get an error on the calculation stage that weight is an undeclared identifier. No problems with age though.

I'm guessing the if function is causing the problem. I'm sure it's something really silly i'm overlooking.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks

Comment: Read up on variable scope and basic language characteristics (like = vs. ==)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a local variable (like `float weight = ...`) it's only visible within the inner-most curly-brace enclosed block. So,

```
if (...)
{
    float weight = ...;
    // weight is visible here
}

// weight is not visible here
```

You should move `float weight;` to before the if; something like this:

```
//Put weight value into a float
float weight;

if (btnKG.selected)
{
    weight = ([valWeight.text floatValue]);
}
else
{
    weight = ([valWeight.text floatValue]/2.20462);
}



//calculate
float bmr = weight * age;
```

(EDIT: And incorporated other fix from Anoop)

Comment: perfect, works properly thanks. Thanks for taking the time to explain why it didn't work, def helps me understand what's going on so I won't make the same mistake going forward.

Comment: One should never use `== YES` for checking boolean type.

Answer (score 1):

`(btnKG.selected = YES)` is incorrect use `(btnKG.selected == YES)`

`=` is used for assingment.

`==` is for comparing.

In your code you are mistakenly assigning the value YES to btnKG.Selected, that is why you are not getting expected result.

Also,

`float weight`  is local to the block { and }. And you are trying to use it later in calculation. Declare the variable weight out side of { & } inside the method, so that you can use it withing he current method.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, appreciate it.